# Contingency table of unique ids

Tags: r, data.table

Example Data:

```
id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6)
comm <- c("Called","Called","Emailed","Called", "Called","Emailed","Called", "Emailed","Called", "Emailed", "Other", "Other")
called <- c("Called", "Called", "Not Called", "Called", "Called", "Not Called", "Called","Not Called", "Called", "Not Called", "Not Called", "Not Called")
emailed <- c("Not Emailed","Not Emailed","Emailed", "Not Emailed", "Not Emailed", "Emailed","Not Emailed", "Emailed", "Not Emailed","Emailed", "Not Emailed", "Not Emailed")
returned <- c("Returned", "Returned", "Returned", "Not Returned", "Not Returned","Returned", "Not Returned", "Not Returned", "Not Returned", "Not Returned", "Not Returned", "Not Returned")
data <- data.table(id, comm, called, emailed, returned)
```

I want to create the following two tables:
[image]

So the tables for the example data should look like this:
[image]

I've tried the following (along with other ways that got erased):

```
table(data$called, data$emailed)
       Emailed Not Emailed
  Called           0           6
  Not Called       4           2
```

But the problem is that counts the number of times calls/emails are made. However, I want it to count the number of unique accounts that are called/emailed/both, not the number of calls/emails made.

Edit to Add: I've realized that I made a mistake with what the second table should be. Here is what it should be.[image]

Comment: according to the table you shared at the beginning of the post, the table result seems to be good. If your filter the data.table `data` with `called = 'Called'`, there are 6 observations, and all have `emailed = 'Not Emailed'`

Comment: That table shows no ids were both called and emailed when ids 1,4, & 5 were both called and emailed.

Comment: @AmandaR. So you want the ids that have been emailed/called at any point to be counted as emailed/called and others to be counted as not emailed/called, correct? In which case, your second example table does not match the data you have provided (ids 1 & 3 have both been emailed at some point)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first table, you can do something like:

```
pvt <- data[, .(
        called=if(any(comm=="Called")) "Called" else "Not Called", 
        emailed=if(any(comm=="Emailed")) "Emailed" else "Not Emailed"), 
    by=.(id)]
dcast(pvt, called ~ emailed, uniqueN, value.var="id")
```

output:

```
       called Emailed Not Emailed
1:     Called       3           1
2: Not Called       1           1
```

For the 2nd table, it is not clear how you handle cases where person is called and emailed but only returned the call. If you are ok with person returning either call or email, then for the 2nd table, something like this should work:

```
pvt <- data[, .(
        called=if(any(comm=="Called")) "Called" else "Not Called", 
        emailed=if(any(comm=="Emailed")) "Emailed" else "Not Emailed", 
        returned=if(any(returned=="Returned")) "Returned" else "Not Returned"),
    by=.(id)]
dcast(pvt, called ~ emailed, function(x) sum(x=="Returned") / length(x), 
    value.var="returned")
```

output:

```
       called   Emailed Not Emailed
1:     Called 0.3333333           0
2: Not Called 1.0000000           0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count for each combination of `called` and `emailed` the number of unique ids. I think that is what you want:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(called, emailed) %>%
  summarise(n_id = n_distinct(id)) %>%
  spread(key = emailed, value = n_id)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   called [2]
  called     Emailed `Not Emailed`
  <chr>        <int>         <int>
1 Called          NA             4
2 Not Called       4             1
```

## EDIT:

Using `data.table` you can also do:

```
data[, .(n_id = uniqueN(id)), by = .(called, emailed)] %>%
  spread(key = emailed, value = n_id)

       called Emailed Not Emailed
1:     Called      NA           4
2: Not Called       4           1
```

Comment: Neither of these ways give the desired result.